# JQuery : getting checkbox value and put it in table

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to get checkbox value using jQuery and put it in my table when submitting. The rest of jQuery code is perfectly working, but only checkbox part give me headache. I tried this one, but it does not work.

Yours suggestions, please.

Thanks in advance

// HTML

```
if ($('#screen_').is(":checked")) {
  $('#screen_display').val();
} else if ($('#garantie').is(":checked")) {
  $('#garantie_display').val();
} else if ($('#imprimante').is(":checked")) {
  $('#printer_display').val();
} else if ($('#souris').is(":checked")) {
  $('#mouse_display').val();
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="screen_" value="screen_" />
  <label for="screen">Screen</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="garantie" value="garantie" />
  <label for="garantie">Garantie</label><br>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="printer" value="printer" />
  <label for="Printer">Printer</label><br>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mouse" value="mouse" />
  <label for="mouse">Mouse</label><br><br>
</div>
<hr><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn_commander" value="Commander">

<table id="Display">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="screen_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="garantie_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="printer_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="mouse_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: How is this related to CSS? You didn't tag `javascript` and `jQuery` but instead tagged `CSS`?

Comment: Sorry. Thanks to mention it. My bad..

Comment: made code into snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is checking if the input is checked in the starting. You need to check when the form is submitted. Secondly, you are not correctly updating the text of the table. Try this:

```js
function submit(){
    if ($('#screen_').is(":checked")) {
        $('#screen_display').html($("#screen_").val());
    }
    if ($('#garantie').is(":checked")) {
        $('#garantie_display').html($("#garantie").val());
    }
    if ($('#printer').is(":checked")) {
        $('#printer_display').html($("#printer").val());
    }
    if ($('#mouse').is(":checked")) {
        $('#mouse_display').html($("#mouse").val());
    }
}
// changed else if to only if to check on all input clicks.
// fixed your ids since some were invalid
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="screen_" value = "screen_" />
    <label for="screen">Screen</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="garantie" value="garantie"/>
    <label for="garantie">Garantie</label><br>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="printer" value="printer"/>
    <label for="Printer">Printer</label><br>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="mouse" value="mouse"/>
<label for="mouse">Mouse</label><br><br>
</div>
<hr><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn_commander" onclick="submit()"  value="Commander">

<table id="Display">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td id="screen_display"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td id="garantie_display"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td id="printer_display"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td id="mouse_display"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Alex try this.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest adding data attributes to point to the targets and then do what you wish for those checked checkboxes targets.  I also blanked the unchecked targets but you can build upon that.

I prevented the default of the submit button but you probably have these in a form and want to also prevent that here? Odd to have a submit type perhaps when you are changing the page.

```js
$('.cool-stuff').on('check-me', function() {
  const checkboxes = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(index, ckelem) {
    const cbx = $(ckelem);
    const myTargetSel = cbx.data('target-selector');
    $(myTargetSel).text(cbx.val());
  });
  checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)").each(function(index, ckelem) {
    const cbx = $(ckelem);
    const myTargetSel = cbx.data('target-selector');
    $(myTargetSel).text('');
  });
});

$('.btn_commander').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.cool-stuff').trigger('check-me');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cool-stuff">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="screen_" value="screen_" data-target-selector="#screen_display" />
    <label for="screen">Screen</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="garantie" value="garantie" data-target-selector="#garantie_display" />
    <label for="garantie">Garantie</label><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="printer" value="printer" data-target-selector="#printer_display" />
    <label for="Printer">Printer</label><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mouse" value="mouse" data-target-selector="#mouse_display" />
    <label for="mouse">Mouse</label><br><br>
  </div>
  <hr><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn_commander" value="Commander">
</div>
<table id="Display">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="screen_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="garantie_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="printer_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="mouse_display"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note this is a bit "verbose" just for clarity and can be reduced down a bit.